# How to reset a FileBrowse or set a FileBrowse to a given path in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I am using PySimpleGUI. I have the following snippet:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


layout = [[sg.Text('File', size=(4, 1)), sg.Input(key="-FILE-", default_text="browse!", size=(128, 2)), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Button("Select file", key="-SELECT_FILE-"), sg.Button("Cancel", key="-SELECT_CANCEL-")]]

window = sg.Window('test reset browse', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "-SELECT_CANCEL-":
        window.FindElement("-FILE-").Update("cancel!")
        # I want to reset also the FileBrowse initial path

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Any idea on how to reset / set to a given path the FileBrowse when canceling (comment line)?

Or formulated another way:

- given that browse has been used to select a path
- given that the cancel button is pressed

how to either:

- reset the path to the initial path that was proposed the very first time the browsing was started

OR

- how to set by hand the new initial path for the next browsing

?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this, as per [this github issue](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/1964) answer from the creator of PySimpleGUI themself.

It turns out, if we add a key to your `sg.FileBrowse` object like so:

```py
sg.FileBrowse(key="-FILEBROWSE-",)
```

then one may simply write

```py
window["-FILEBROWSE-"].InitialFolder = r"C:\\"
```

obviously replacing the string with whatever path is desired. This, for example, will set the initial folder to the C drive.

See your full code with my changes:

```py
layout = [
    [
        sg.Text('File', size=(4, 1)),
        sg.Input(key="-FILE-", default_text="browse!", size=(128, 2)),
        sg.FileBrowse(key="-FILEBROWSE-",) # Add key here
    ],
    [
        sg.Button("Select file", key="-SELECT_FILE-"),
        sg.Button("Cancel", key="-SELECT_CANCEL-")
    ]
]

window = sg.Window('test reset browse', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "-SELECT_CANCEL-":
        window.FindElement("-FILE-").Update("cancel!")
        # I want to reset also the FileBrowse initial path

        # Set initial folder here
        window["-FILEBROWSE-"].InitialFolder = r"C:\\"

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the default values of Sg.FileBrowse. As you can see there is an `initial_folder` option you can use. I'd suggest you use this.

```py
def FileBrowse(button_text='Browse', target=(ThisRow, -1), file_types=(("ALL Files", "*.*"),), initial_folder=None,
               tooltip=None, size=(None, None), auto_size_button=None, button_color=None, change_submits=False,
               enable_events=False, font=None, disabled=False,
               pad=None, key=None, metadata=None):
```